# Authentication Token Security

Tags: php, security, authentication, access-token

What are the major flaws with authentication following the following logic.

User logs into `a.example.com` and clicks "Login to b.example.com". This link generates a random string and saves it in the `b.example.com` database. It then redirects to `b.example.com/remotelogin.php?token=therandomstring` which checks the database for that string and logs the user in.

The only problem I could think of that it needs for security is a time limit for the token to be valid, which could be like 30 seconds or something.

Comment: I think this would be better on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: have you read about OAuth? That would be a more secure approach

Comment: If the token is time limited I see very little possibility for problems.

Comment: time limited, but the limit must be set in the database, and not in the url or cookie. also, make tokens single use, so once they have been used, remove or invalidate them. then you shouldnt see any problems.

Comment: implementing my own OAuth for a couple networked websites seems like a vast pain for something that should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly a user authentication scheme. User authentication is about who the user is. Also it is not very practical.

e.g. If it expires in 30 seconds and the user makes a refresh in 40 seconds? what then?

What about malicious users sending links and having people logging in the web page? Or what about malicious users flooding your database with loggins?

Do you plan to have ssl or in those 30 seconds you are open to replay attacks? The scheme you are proposing is not good at all and has many many more stuff that can go wrong.

I guess what I am saying mostly is this (without trying be offensive):

If you do not hold any user relevant info why do you bother authenticating? Against who doing what? For example you cannot use this scheme in a social net app or a bank app or a forum like this. If you do not do anything security sensitive then yes your scheme has no security flows but it has no flaws because it does not hold sensitive info.

Comment: *"40 seconds"*: fixed by choosing an appropriate timeout; *"malicious users sending links"*: that is prevented by the server-server communication behind the scenes and the time limit; *"flooding database"*: please explain how that is terrifically problematic; *"SSL"*: yes, let's assume this is over SSL, then there's virtually no chance of a problem. Your criticism seems a bit too aggressive and has little substance to show for it.

Comment: 30 second expiration is for the login request. once the login request is made, they would get a session for that website with its own expiration but the token used for authentication is no longer valid.

Comment: I am sorry if I sounded aggressive. Not my intention. Again though authentication is about who the user is not about its (yes its) ability to follow a link. How is an authentication usefull if it is unable to hold user relevant info. Also if you make it so easy for botnets a malicious user will fill gigabytes in your db by simply following the link by the millions. Also what do you mean "prevented by the server-server communication behind the scenes"?

Comment: It would add the string to a row for the matching user on the other website. It would be modifying one single row. That won't increase the size of the database.

Comment: also remember you have to be logged into website A to generate a token for website B so... it knows who the user is.

Comment: So site b needs always site a to be logged in? You are trying to have an openId style of authentication?

Comment: Does it matter? That's not relevant to the question I posted.

Comment: Well yes. Let's say I want to go to site b two days after I first visited it? Will I have to go back to a and then to b so as to log again? maybe you want something like that: http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/

Comment: My question was asking what are the security issues with what I proposed. By suggesting alternate solutions I am not understanding any security issues with my proposed solution.

That said: You would be able to login to site b on its own using the same username/password for site A. Alternatively: you could login to site a and click the link to login to site b. (while on site b, you would have a link to login to site a)

Comment: Merbist link had very helpful info but I'm not entirely sure how my proposed solution differs much from it. They're using iframes for cross-domain sessions but is there an issue with allowing individual sites to generate authentication tokens when receiving login requests for other websites (again considering its happening in the background on a set of networked sites, not a general auth solution consumed by the public)

Comment: mainly the difference is the encrypted token the authentication system returns (which solves the issue of deciding 40 seconds) and also the fact that you implement login in one place only. Your solution is a simple one but you have to take care many things (replay attacks and breaking your crypto algorithm from way too many tokens collected from urls -provided you don't use crypto correctly-).